# Provided data source did not match an array, Observable, or DataSource while using Observable and not using static json

Tags: json, angular, httpclient, angular-material-table

I am recieving json object from REST API back end, but receiving Provided data source did not match an array, Observable, or DataSource Exception. I tried the same with just using json data and it was working fine.

Html File

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="applicantList" class="mat-elevation-z8">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let applicant"> {{applicant?.applicant.id}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="applicantName">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let applicant"> {{applicant?.applicant.applicantName}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="gender">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Gender </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let applicant"> {{applicant?.applicant.gender}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="district">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> District </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let applicant"> {{applicant.district}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="state">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> State </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let applicant"> {{applicant.state}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="pincode">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Pincode </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let applicant"> {{applicant.pincode}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="ownership">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Ownership </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let applicant"> {{applicant.ownership}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="govtId">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Government ID </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let applicant"> {{applicant?.applicant.govtId}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="idNumber">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID Number </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let applicant"> {{applicant?.applicant.idNumber}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="category">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Category </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let applicant"> {{applicant.category}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="loadApplied">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Load Applied </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let applicant"> {{applicant.loadApplied}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="dateOfApplication">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Date Of Application </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let applicant"> {{applicant.dateOfApplication}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="dateOfApproval">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Date Of Approval </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let applicant"> {{applicant.dateOfApproval}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="modifiedDate">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Modified Date </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let applicant"> {{applicant.modifiedDate}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Status </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let applicant"> {{applicant.status}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="reviewerId">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Reviewer Id </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let applicant"> {{applicant?.reviewer.reviewerId}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="reviewerName">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Reviewer Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let applicant"> {{applicant?.reviewer.reviewerName}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="reviewerComments">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Reviewer Comments </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let applicant"> {{applicant.reviewerComments}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

</table>
```

Component file:

```
  applicantList!:ApplicantionModel[];

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'applicantName', 'gender', 'district','state','pincode','ownership','govtId','idNumber','category',
                                'loadApplied','dateOfApplication','dateOfApproval','modifiedDate','status','reviewerId','reviewerName','reviewerComments'];

  dataSource=new MatTableDataSource<ApplicantionModel>;

  constructor(private dataService:DataService){}

  ngOnInit(): void { 
    this.dataService.loadApplicationlist().subscribe(data =>{
      this.applicantList=data;

      this.dataSource.data=this.applicantList;
      console.log(this.applicantList);
      }
    );

  }
```

My Service File

```
    loadApplicationlist(): Observable<any>{
      return this.http.get<any>(this.localUrl+'/application/getApplicationList');
    }
```

My JSOn file

```
[
  {
    "applicant": {
        "id": 1,
        "applicantName": "JOHN",
        "gender": "Male",
        "govtId": "PAN",
        "idNumber": 6349499
    },
    "district": "East",
    "state": "DELHI",
    "pincode": 110065,
    "ownership": "INDIVIDUAL",
    "category": "Commerical",
    "loadApplied": 7,
    "dateOfApplication": "0007-02-10T18:30:00.000+00:00",
    "dateOfApproval": "0007-02-10T18:30:00.000+00:00",
    "modifiedDate": "0008-02-10T18:30:00.000+00:00",
    "status": "Pending",
    "reviewer": {
        "reviewerId": 101,
        "reviewerName": "HEM CHAND"
    },
    "reviewerComments": "Documents verification in progress"
}
]
```

I am fully confused what is causing the issue as it is only happening in observable. What is the issue and why is it happening.

i tried with static json and it worked fine. I tried multiple solutions but i did not understand the issue.

Comment: You're asserting (with exclamation mark) that `applicantList` is not null or undefined, but you don't initialize it with any value, so the template might actually try to iterate over it (assuming it already has a value), but since the subscription is async - it still has no value. So, try removing the exclamation mark, or put `*ngIf="applicantList.length > 0` in table tag.

Comment: In your html why not `[dataSource]="dataSource"`?

Comment: I tired that appproach and its still showing the error

Comment: What is the error that you see?

Comment: This is the error:

core.mjs:8416 ERROR Error: Provided data source did not match an array, Observable, or DataSource
    at getTableUnknownDataSourceError (table.mjs:1024:12)
    at MatTable._observeRenderChanges (table.mjs:1763:19)
    at MatTable.ngAfterContentChecked (table.mjs:1415:18)
    at callHook (core.mjs:2460:18)
    at callHooks (core.mjs:2419:17)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.mjs:2370:9)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:10383:21)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.mjs:11355:17)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:10366:9)
    at refreshComponent (core.mjs:11401:13)

Comment: Are you sure your api returns an array? exactly like the json file? The error message indicates otherwise. Also change to `dataSource=new MatTableDataSource<ApplicantionModel>([]);` to initialize the data source with an empty array